# Missing mouse-over API documentation in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, intellisense

A mouse-over on .NET library classes should normally result in a popup that includes information gleaned from API documentation. For example, this pop-up shows the summary text for `FieldInfo`:

[image]

I recently had to do some work on a project that targets .NET 4.6, and the summary info didn't show. If I temporarily retargeted the project to  4.7.2, the summary info *did* show up. Looking into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6`, I saw all the assemblies, but no .xml files, which is where the documentation lives. The `v4.7.2` folder, on the other hand, *did* have .xml files.

Then I noticed a folder named `v4.X`, which had nothing *but* .xml files. I copied those into the `v4.6` folder, alongside all the assemblies, and voila! VS was working as expected again.

My guess is that VS is meant to pick up any missing documentation (presumably common to many versions) from `v4.X`, but that this functionality is broken. Any insiders around who either know or could file a bug with the right team? (Or, alternatively, tell me where my analysis went wrong?)

### Visual Studio version info

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 Version 16.7.7
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.7.7+30621.155
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.8.04084
Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA412
```

Comment: Any update about this issue? Please check if my answer helps or not and feel free to let us know.

Comment: I added a comment to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually**, I did not faced the same issue in my **VS2019 16.7.7**. And you can see my side, the folder **v4.6** contains all the xml files for the assemblies.

[image]

And when I target to `Net Framework 4.6` in VS.

[image]

I can see the summary text for `FieldInfo`.

[image]

So you may did other incorrect actions or some third-party extensions or programs caused the loss of these files. And it causes VS IDE damage and defects.

You could try to the following suggestions:

**Suggestions**

**1)** please install [Net Framework 4.6 Developer SDK and Runtime program](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) again from the official website to overwrite the previous installation.

**2)** open control panel-->Programs-->Programs and Features-->right-click on `Microsoft .Net Framework 4.6 Targeting Pack` and choose **Repair**

**3)** [repair VS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) or update VS since there is a new release version `16.8`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have done all of the above without seeing any changes -- uninstalling and reinstalling framework versions might make a difference, but I'm not bothered enough by this (at the moment, at least) to go that route. Mostly I'm curious about the purpose of the v4.x folder...

Comment: Actually, it seems [an open issue for that](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5670). And pure repair doesn't seem to work.  Your method is a workaround so far. And 4.x framework  is a mixed old framework for net4.0, 4.5,4.5.1,4.5.2. And since 4.6.1, it has been abandoned. I will find any tips and other workarounds  further.